# How to download on open SFTP file in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: php, netbeans, web, ide

I'm using Netbeans 8 with remote files project.
The files are located on remote server and Netbeans access them via SFTP.

I would like that Netbeans will download fresh copy every time I open a file, same as notepad++ does.

any idea how to do that?
couldn't find solution on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here after looking for an answer for the same question. I couldn't find automatic download of fresh copy during every time you open the IDE but there is an option to Download manually.

**Right click on "Source Files" of your project in "Projects" window and click "Download".**

If you are looking only to download files which are modified in server directly then you go for "Synchronize" which is just below the "Download".

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to go on new project, and then press your java file, then make a name for your file then you are in.